# Put Gitlab CI's Runner output in wiki

Tags: git, gitlab, doxygen

What would be the best (most efficient way) to put the output of one of my gitlab runners (in this case a generated doxygen documentation) in the repo's wiki?
Pushing it manually to the wiki's git repo didn't work out so well, sice the CSS an JS of the doxygen page is not loaded properly.

What would be the correct (intended) workflow in gitlab for putting static pages in the wiki or on any other project-related location?

Answer (score 1):

The wiki pages of Gitlab are themselves accessible through a git repository you can clone, edit and push to.

I guess you can add a script at the end of your runner sequence that would do just that.
You can find more info on this process here :
https://gitlab.com/*username*/*repo*/wikis/git_access

Or by clicking the link 'Clone repository' accessible from the wiki tab of your repo :

[image: Wiki clone link location]

Comment: As I already stated in my question, pushing it in the wiki's Git repo doesn't work out well, because CSS and JS are not loaded properly

Comment: Then that's your problem. Git push is the way to go for updating the wiki. Can you elaborate on the problems you have with the CSS and JS files ?

Comment: By saying it I realised that something was wrong from the start :) The wiki doesn't support standard HTML/CSS/JS, but requires the content to be in Markdown format. Hopefully doxygen seems to support it : https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/markdown.html

Comment: To be complete (sorry for the multi comment) if you really need HTML documentation, you should have a look at Gitlab Pages (But it's for EE only as far as I know) : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/index.html#gitlab-pages